# How to make query string always return an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string

I am using query string (https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to parse the params in the URL like so:

`http://www.website.com/?filter="bags"&filter="shirts"`

However, if I have no filter or just one filter it will return either a string or undefined:

```
http://www.website.com/?filter="bags" // returns 'bags'
http://www.website.com/ // returns undefined
```

The reason being I need to feed this result into functions / methods that use an array.

One solution I thought of is to sort of create condition depending on what it returns:

```
if (typeof query == 'string') {
    query = [query];
} else if (query == undefined) {
    query = [];
}
```

But this seems not optimal. Wondering if the result can just be an array all time instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing much you can do. Though, you can use ternary operator to reduce some code. The following will return an empty array if `query` does not have anything:

```
if(!Array.isArray(query))
  query = !!query ? [query] : [];
```

Comment: You edited your answer exactly like mine but what is the purpose of posting the same answer?

Comment: @soroushchehresa, the same I could say, like I have used ternary operator even before you answered......more over, without any explanation what the code is doing how the answer could help someone!!!

Comment: Maybe it can be a reason but not compelling!

Comment: This solution seems to wrap the array into another array. I think coz the first condition satisfies both string and array.. so it wraps the array into another array.

Comment: @catandmouse, you are right. Just wanted to know, in any case, could `query` be an array before modifying?

Comment: Yes, if the string on the url have more than 2 params (e.g. filter="bags"&filter="shorts"), then it will automatically return an array.

Comment: @catandmouse, then you can check the whether `query` is already an array or not. If not an array then execute the code......I have updated the answer.....please check

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do:

```
query = !!query ? Array.isArray(query) ? query : [query] : [];
```

or:

```
if(!!query) {
  if(!Array.isArray(query)) {
    query = [query];
  }
} else {
  query = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The reason being I need to feed this result into functions / methods
>   that use an array.

i think the better solution is instead of checking query is `array` or`undefined`, you can add default param of function/method to be array

example

```
function yourFunction(query = []){
    return query;
}
```

Comment: so what if it's a string or an integer?

Comment: @vol7ron don't worry  qs parse will return either a string or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way, `if` condition checks query is undefined or not.

```
if (query) {
   query = [query];
} else {
   query = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var filter = [];

if(query) {
  filter.push(query);
}
```

This way, filter would always be an array and contain the query filters, if provided. This pattern is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize an empty query. Suppose, your query is stored in state, then:

```
const { query } = this.state || { query: [] }
```

Or, simply initialize the query with empty array in the state:

```
state = {
  query: [] // rather than ''
}
```

Now, you should only set the query state when it has value inside your handler:

```
const query = e.target.value // or whatever the source you get the query from
if(query) {
  this.setState({query: [query]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option in addition to the many existing answers it that you could always wrap it and then filter out the `undefined`s:

```js
let str = 'str';
console.log( [str].filter(v=>v!==undefined) )   // [ 'str' ]

let undf;
console.log( [undf].filter(v=>v!==undefined) )  // [ ]

// Example: filter out undefined
query = [query].filter(v=>v!==undefined)

// Example: passing in a Boolean constructor, since non-empty strings are truthy
query = [query].filter(Boolean)
```